# Call WCF method OnUnload of ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I want call a WCF method when application exit, but, when I try to run ASP.NET application with this code:

```
protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnUnload(e);

    MaChatServer.Service1Client proxy = new MaChatServer.Service1Client();
    proxy.RemoveUser(UsernameStatic);
    if (proxy.GetAllUsers().Count == 0)
    {
        proxy.ResetServer();
    }
}
```

I see this error page:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. For more information about the error and where it originated in the code, refer to the stack trace. Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The server was unable to process the request two to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Comment: did you do as the error message stated? Did you enable tracing to see the actual error?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: How can I enable it?

Comment: Can you open the endpoint in your browser? Does the service working?

Comment: Yes yes, It does not working only when I add this: protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnUnload(e);

    MaChatServer.Service1Client proxy = new MaChatServer.Service1Client();
    proxy.RemoveUser(UsernameStatic);
    if (proxy.GetAllUsers().Count == 0)
    {
        proxy.ResetServer();
    }
}

Comment: I was wondering what happens if you put "base.OnUnload(e)" as the last line in the method? Have you tried this?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing has changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly i suggest you to add config to your host wcf service (.config)

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="debug">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Because you don't have exact error message, your message must be sent to your client

Comment: I've done that but now the pages doen't working, but if I remove         protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnUnload(e);

            MaChatServer.Service1Client proxy = new MaChatServer.Service1Client();
            proxy.RemoveUser(UsernameStatic);
            if (proxy.GetAllUsers().Count == 0)
            {
                proxy.ResetServer();
            }
        }
, it works